# Please wait Animation gif using javascript

Tags: javascript, pleasewait

I am trying to use [this post](http://www.ryantetek.com/2009/06/animated-progress-loading-bar-upon-form-submit-javascript/) in order to get the animated gif for Please wait message.... on button click. However, when I open the sample html page that I am testing on, I get an input box instead of an button with am image.

Below is the html code that I am trying on a test page.

```
 <html>

 <script type="text/javascript">


  function loadSubmit() {
   var ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
  document.getElementById("progress").style.visibility = “visible”;
   setTimeout(function(){ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src},100);
   return true;
    }
    </script>

 <body>
   <p style="visibility:hidden;" id="progress">

  <img id="progress_image" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;" src="ajax-loader.gif" alt=""> Uploading in progress…      </p> 
    <input class="contSubmit" onclick="return loadSubmit()" type=”button” src= "submitinfo_btn.png" /> 

     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your tutorial, the input should be of type "image", not "button".

Comment: It works now...I somehow missed it..thanks for pointing it out. Could you let me know how could I center the image instead of having it on the top left corner of the page

Comment: Do you need to center img or input type="image"?

Comment: I have added in the css to center the image in the center of my page and also changed the input type to image. it works fine...Except that the dots on the circle to not animate on my page...Dont know whats wrong.

Comment: also double check your quotes, as suggested by @Stefan (for example "visible").

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when copy-pasting Code like this.
This is wrong:

```
type=”button”
```

This is right:

```
type="button"
```

Notice the difference? This happens if you copy Code from a website that doesn't have proper formatting for Code enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `input` type to `image`. The `src` is only valid for `image`.

Also, it appears your problem has nothing to do with your "please wait" animated gif, so maybe your title is misleading.